# Pegar o nome textview em laço de repetição

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Como posso pegar o textbox dentro de um For:

Tenho um **For** que percorre 20 vezes e tenho 20 textbox em minha tela, gostaria de saber como poderia pegar todos os textbox que contenha no **name** a palavra "Publicacao" pegar o texto e jogar em uma array.

Comment: Poderia nos esclarer mais sobre a sua dúvida? Tem código de exemplo?

Comment: Você está usando WinForms?

Comment: Jbueno, Sim WinForms

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar um `for` para isso, você pode simplesmente usar uma query em Linq para simplificar isso tudo.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var textos = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().
                                 Where(control => control.Name.Contains("Publicacao")).
                                 Select(txt => txt.Text).ToArray();
```

---

Essa *query* pega, da propriedade `Controls` do formulário, todos os controles que sejam do tipo `TextBox` (ou derivados do mesmo) cujo nome contenha a literal **Publicacao** e depois seleciona apenas o texto dos mesmos, jogando-os no array de string (`string[]`) `textos`.

Comment: Gostei da solução porém não funcionou ele não achou nenhum textbox.

Comment: Os `TextBoxes` estão dentro de algum container na tela? Algo como `panel`, `groupbox`, etc.

Comment: Está sim, dentro de um painel

Comment: Tente trocar o this pelo nome do painel. Algo como panel1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do formulário e executar um linq para pegar os controles com o nome desejado.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(ctrl => ctrl.Name.Contains("Publicacao")).ToList();
```

Comment: Julio, não trouxe nada meus textbox se chamam txtPublicacao. txtPublicacao2, txtPublicacao3

      List<TextBox> textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Where(ctrl => ctrl.Name.Contains("txtPublicacao")).ToList();

Comment: Se os controles estiverem dentro de um painel, realize o mesmo código demonstrado acima, porém troque o this pelo nome do painel.

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode usar um for percorrendo os controles que estão dentro do painel. Nessa função você passa o seu painel, e o for percorrera todos os TextBox, e os que tiverem como nome "Publicacao" serão salvos numa lista de nomes, e retornado.

```
Public Function NomesArray(ByRef painel As Control) As List(Of String)
    Dim ArrayNomes As New List(Of String)

    For Each Control In painel.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
            If DirectCast(Control, txtBusca).Name = "Publicacao" Then
                ArrayNomes.Add(DirectCast(Control, txtBusca).Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return ArrayNomes
End Function
```